# Deactivating Intel Turbo Boost

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i5, turbo-boost

I disabled this option from the BIOS but I don't notice any change in system temperature or fan noise.
The CPU is Core i5 4310U. Is this normal? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what is the operating system? what is the primary goal you are trying to achieve? What was the problem that you are trying to address?  what is the model of the laptop? Did you use any monitoring software to observe the stepping?

Comment: Start -> Power Options. Select the "Power Saver" Power Plan to reduce the performance, power usage and heat generated by the pc/laptop.

Answer (score 5):

It is normal.

Enabling Turbo Boost doesn't mean that your CPU is constantly overclocked. It's just granted permission to overclock some cores in certain circumstances.

If Turbo Boost is enabled **and** CPU is under high load, some cores can be automatically overclocked. Performance gain depends on number of active cores: for example i7-920XM can step up from 2.0 GHz to 3.20 GHz if only one core is active, but only to 2.26 GHz if all 4 cores are active. (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost#Example))

That means that temperature probably won't be affected unless your system is running under heavy load for extended periods of time. Otherwise Turbo Boost doesn't kick in anyway.

There aren't many reason to disable Turbo Boost. One could be to achieve lower latencies in a near-realtime system (for example for sound processing).